# get row from dataframe df1 and search in df2 , if match then copy a specifica columns value from df1 into df2

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have df1:

```
ID  Label1   Label2  Cat
P203  car    ded      34
P560  bk     green    67
P780  blue   black    45
```

df2:

```
ID  Label1   Label2  cat
P903  chyt    dd      0
P560  bk3     green    0
P780  blue2   black2   0 
P880  blue4   black    0
P203  blue9   black1   0
```

I want a result like:

```
ID  Label1   Label2   cat
P903  chyt    dd      0
P560  bk3     green    67
P780  blue2   black2   45 
P880  blue4   black    0
P203  blue9   black1   34
```

df2 is a new dataframe, an updated version of df1, so the only column that remains equal to df1 is 'ID' the other columns were updated with different labels/words. However, df1 has an extra column that was added by hand. I want to retrieve that information and copy into df2 using ID column as key but df2 has to maintain its columns.

I have tried .merge, but it repeats columns, or omits rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
If `ID` is not `index`

```
>>> df2.merge(df1.loc[:,['ID','Cat']], on='ID', how='left').fillna(0)
     ID Label1  Label2  cat   Cat
0  P903   chyt      dd    0   0.0
1  P560    bk3   green    0  67.0
2  P780  blue2  black2    0  45.0
3  P880  blue4   black    0   0.0
4  P203  blue9  black1    0  34.0
```

Or if `ID` is `index` in both dataframes.
[`pd.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
>>> df2.join(df1['Cat']).fillna(0)
     Label1  Label2  cat   Cat
ID
P903   chyt      dd    0   0.0
P560    bk3   green    0  67.0
P780  blue2  black2    0  45.0
P880  blue4   black    0   0.0
P203  blue9  black1    0  34.0
```

[`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
>>> df2.merge(df1['Cat'], on='ID', how='left').fillna(0)
     Label1  Label2  cat   Cat
ID
P903   chyt      dd    0   0.0
P560    bk3   green    0  67.0
P780  blue2  black2    0  45.0
P880  blue4   black    0   0.0
P203  blue9  black1    0  34.0
```

Comment: Do you have `ID` column as index?

Comment: `df1 = df1.set_index('ID')`

Comment: Use this if `ID` is not `index` in both dataframe. `df2.merge(df1.loc[:,['ID','Cat']], on='ID', how='left').fillna(0)`